# How do I assemble the rear brakes on a 2003 Chevy Tracker?

Tags: brakes, chevrolet

Went to replace the rear brake shoes and drums on a 2003 Chevy Tracker and when I pulled off the drum the adjuster, adjuster spring and pawl lever were not hooked up, they were just laying in there. This was both sides so I was wondering if anyone had a diagram of how this parts get installed.

Comment: Yes it is having trouble with the pawl lever and adjuster spring need some kind of image to display how to put it back together

Comment: Are you the OP?

Comment: When ever you remove brake drums from a vehicle you must always unadjust them first. Over time the area of the shoes in contact with the drum will make a groove on the inside of the drum. If you now bang and clatter the drum off of the assembly, the drag on the shoes across the drum will nearly always pull the retaining springs off of their pins. This is what has happened. The adjuster must always be slackened off by tooling through the backplate or drum hole provided, or even the wheel bolt hole.

Answer (score 4):

Does this look like what you have?

[image]